# How do i redraw a shape in ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3

My question is: how do I redraw a shape using only code?

Short comment on the task itself. I've an eventListener, which grabs clicks on stage and stage resizes. Both execute the same function - `redrawEvents(evt:Event)`. The stage contains a number of blocks, which represent certain events. On each redraw these blocks are repositioned, and also lines (which represent connections between events) are drawn.

I've figured out a way to reposition all the blocks, but I got stuck on redrawing lines.

I'm using a single shape to hold all the lines, because lines, unlike blocks, are not interactive. Since the whole point of the application is creating sets of interconnected events, I have to modify this shape every time a new block is created, which also calls redraw function.

Here's the code I use to modify the shape

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,redrawEvents);

function redrawEvents (evt:Event) {
    var lines:Shape = new Shape();
    lines.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xFFFFFF, .75);
    lines.graphics.clear();
    for (var k:int = 0; k < connections.length; k++){
        lines.graphics.moveTo(eventList[connections[k][0]].x + 50, eventList[connections[k][0]].y + 50);
        lines.graphics.lineTo(eventList[connections[k][1]].x + 50, eventList[connections[k][1]].y + 50);
    }
    addChild(lines);
}
```

However, whenever the shape is modified, it still leaves the 'older versions' of itself on screen, and i don't want that. I tried to create and delete instances, varions type conversions, but still that haven't solved the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you draw the lines, you're adding a new `Shape` to the stage. You can keep a reference to it and remove it from the display list each time, or just use one instance and the `clear()` method of `Graphics` before drawing the new set of lines.

Comment: I've updated the code up there ^ and replied to evilguy.
Still, it's either I am doing something wrong, or these recommendations just don't solve my problem. Now I don't have any lines on stage :)

Comment: @Loki `lines` is a variable local to your event handler - you're calling `clear()` on a new instance of `Shape`, so the only thing you're clearing is the line style. You need to make `lines` a class field (or otherwise keep it somewhere), instantiate it only once (not each time the event fires) and call `clear()` before any other drawing commands.

Comment: Okay then, let's say i will put the `lines` and `lineStyle` definitions along with global variables, outside of `redrawEvents`. Then how do I access `lines` in this function?

Comment: You just do `lines.graphics.clear()`, `lines.graphics.lineStyle(whatever)` and then the drawing commands in the event handler. You don't need to call `lineStyle` after initializing, because it would get reset by `clear()` in the event handler anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating new Shape instance every time on redraw?
Did you try removeChild(lines)?

Comment: i have, but that deletes the instace of the shape, and i always need to keep 1 instance on stage, showing connections between the objects

Comment: @Loki: You need to remove the old instance before adding the new one.

Comment: Well, obviously I have to remove the child before modifying the shape, and create a new child after modifying. Still, when i tried to do that - I've got an error, saying that i can't remove a child that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Loki : What if U'll make this variable local. Put
`var lines:Shape;`
before you set CLICK listener, and in redraw function U'll do:

`if(contains(lines))
{
    removeChild(lines);
    lines = new Shape();
}`

Comment: I've checked this thing out, and took a note of `contains` method, many thanks, this is going to get handy later in my development